# OpenCV classes and functions doesn't work

Tags: qt, opencv

I am trying to run my application Qt + OpenCV , but when I use a class or function opencv application does not run , returning an error :

This is the header file :

```
MyQLabel *myQLabelFrameUmHSV ;
     MyQLabel *myQLabelFrameDoisHSV ;
     MyQLabel *myQLabelFrameTresHSV ;
     MyQLabel *myQLabelFrameQuatroHSV ;

    cv :: Mat matFrameConv ;

    cv :: Mat matFrameUmHSV ;
    cv :: Mat matFrameDoisHSV ;
    cv :: Mat matFrameTresHSV ;
    cv :: Mat matFrameQuatroHSV ;

    QImage imageFrameUmHSV ;
    QImage imageFrameDoisHSV ;
    QImage imageFrameTresHSV ;
    QImage imageFrameQuatroHSV ;

    cv :: VideoCapture cap ;

    QImage * toQImage ( cv :: Mat matImage ) ;
    / / void TimerEvent ( QTimerEvent * t ) ;
    doFindClicle void ();
```

exited with code -1073741511

However , if I declare the classes as a pointer , the application runs ( however, I do not instantiate pointers , only declare , but not use , otherwise , the application does not run again . )

```
 MyQLabel* myQLabelFrameUmHSV ;
     MyQLabel* myQLabelFrameDoisHSV ;
     MyQLabel* myQLabelFrameTresHSV ;
     MyQLabel* myQLabelFrameQuatroHSV ;

    cv :: Mat * matFrameConv ;

    cv :: Mat * matFrameUmHSV ;
    cv :: Mat * matFrameDoisHSV ;
    cv :: Mat * matFrameTresHSV ;
    cv :: Mat * matFrameQuatroHSV ;

    QImage imageFrameUmHSV ;
    QImage imageFrameDoisHSV ;
    QImage imageFrameTresHSV ;
    QImage imageFrameQuatroHSV ;

    cv :: VideoCapture * cap ;

    QImage * toQImage ( cv :: Mat * matImage ) ;
    / / void TimerEvent ( QTimerEvent * t ) ;
    doFindClicle void ();
```

the. pro

```
QT + = core gui

greaterThan ( QT_MAJOR_VERSION , 4 ) : QT + = widgets

TARGET = Projeto_FPGA
TEMPLATE = app

IncludePath + = D : \ opencv \ build \ include
LIBS + = - LD : \ opencv \ build \ x86 \ mingw \ lib \
            llibopencv_core246 - \
            llibopencv_highgui246 - \
            - llibopencv_imgproc246

SOURCES + = main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \
    myqlabel.cpp

Mainwindow.h HEADERS + = \
    myqlabel.h

FORMS + = mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES + = \
    Icons.qrc
```

( Qt 5.0.2 MinGW 32 bit ) and ( OpenCV 2:46 )

Already, I thank

Comment: `* MyQLabel myQLabelFrameUmHSV ;`   // <-- what's this ?

Comment: hmm, this is an inherited QLabel, I need to convert and display the frame Mat

Comment: he meant that this doesn't look like a C++ declaration, it should look like: `MyQLabel *myQLabelFrameUmHSV;`. So we suspect that first thing you should do is learn basics of C++.

Comment: this must be a bug on the site (or not), in my code this is declared corretly

Comment: ah, edited. so the above comment is obsolete. now what's still missing, is the error you get when *not* using pointers.

Comment: error: exited with code -1073741511 (can't find googling)